# Apache2 html-link redirects to about:blank instead of the in href specified website

Tags: google-chrome, apache-http-server, webserver, html, html5

I created a self-hosted website powered by a Raspberry Pi and Apache2.
In my html file I used following line to display a link to another webpage:

```html
<p>Map link: <a title="MyTitle" href="page.domain.com" target="_blank">displayed_link</a></p>
```

This shows (non functional link):

[displayed_link](http://abc)

Whenever I click the link on my website though, it opens a new tab like it should with the `target="_blank"` attribute, but it shows `about:blank` in my browsers URL-field and no page content. Only when I click into the URL-field and hit ENTER, it actually loads the URL specified in `href="page.domain.com"`.

Is this just me, writing bad html code or is it maybe my browser not loading the link on purpose?

I am using the latest apache2 version and Google Chrome as my browser. The webserver uses the http protocol on port 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `href` attribute takes a URL als value. `page.domain.com` is not a valid URL.

Try putting `href="https://page.domain.com/"` in your `<a>` tag instead.